# Why did we have to declare a package at the top of the code?

Tags: java

I'm a new learner of java and i made an "hello youtube" program as i watch a youtube tutorial.
However, it didn't work at the first time in this form.

```
class apples{
   public static void main(String args[]){
       System.out.println("hello youtube!");
  }
}
```

So i learnt and pictured two solutions below.

[image]

*First solution*: `package bucky;` required at the top of the code. What exactly did we solve adding package bucky?

What is the meaning of *the other solution*
I mean we are moving a class named apples.java, why are we especially moving class for example?

Comment: Your class is named `apples`. It is convention in java to use capital letters for class names. You may think it is unimportant, but actually, I spent a half minute realising that "apples.java" referred to your java source file. Had it been "Apples.java", I would have been thinking with, "That's a class, that is."

Comment: A package is a directory but in java it is accessed with `.`, e.g. in includes you say `bucky.Apples` (I recommend to have upper case class names). So if your file apples.java is in a directory called bucky it has to be in package bucky... or, the 2nd option, you can move it to the default package (not recommended), then you don't need the package declaration.

Comment: tutorial introduction to the concept of packages: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: Java uses file system directories to store packages. Have a look at  [Naming a Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What exactly did we solve adding package bucky?

By adding package you specify in which folder your class is located.

> I mean we are moving a class named apples.java, why are we especially
>   moving class for example?

The Eclipse IDE is telling you a way to solve your error by moving your class to a good package...

**Take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm) tutorial**

Answer (score 0):

Package declaration is **optional**.

If you **don't declare** - you put all classes is `default` package (bad coding style).

If you **declare** it - do it on the first line of file.